# Cycles - Rendering with RTX 2060 CUDA Error

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I'm running the latest version of Blender 2.79 and I'm trying to render in cycles with a RTX 2060. I'm unable to render anything. At first I received the Error **"CUDA binary kernel for this graphics card compute capability (7.5) not found."**

I followed the steps in this youtube video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sZjIQGLieB4
*Basically downloading a filter and kernel file and moving it into 
C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender\2.79\scripts\addons\cycles\lib*

After doing that I no longer received the first error, now I'm receiving this error **"CUDA error: Not found in cuModuleGetGlobal(&cumem &cubytes, cuModule, bind_name.c_str()), line 729"**

Any recommendations or fixes anyone can suggest?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need to use the Blender 2.8 beta for rendering with a 20-series card. They updated some technical CUDA stuff that allows newer generation GPUs to be compatible, but 2.79 naturally hasn't received those updates.

Hope this helps, and good luck!

Comment: Thanks, just got 2.8 up and running and was able to render.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the 2.79 version from the [latest builds](https://builder.blender.org/download/). It works with the 20 series as well.